# Inheritance with same default template arguments

Tags: c++

Given the following class:

```
template<typename BoringArg1 = int,
         typename BoringArg2 = char,
         typename ThisDefinitionIsSoLong = int,
         typename WhoWroteThis = double>
class A {
    // ...
};
```

Now I want to inherit from `A`, keeping it templated:

```
template<typename BoringArg1 = int,
         typename BoringArg2 = char,
         typename ThisDefinitionIsSoLong = int,
         typename WhoWroteThis = double>
class B : public A<BoringArg1, BoringArg2, ThisDefinitionIsSoLong, WhoWroteThis> {
    // ...
};
```

As you can see, the templated arguments are repeated. Is it possible to avoid this ? Moreover, the default arguments of `A` may change. It would be nice to reflect these change in `B` without code modification in `B`. One solution I see is to make a bunch of template type `DefaultTypeXXX`. It's a bit tedious, and can't really change the order and count of template arguments of `A` (but this condition is lesser important). Is there any alternative ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your parameters are of the same sort (types, non-types or templates), you may let `B` accept a parameter pack

```
template<typename... Args>
class B : public A<Args...> {
// ...
};
```

This will either forward the corresponding arguments to `A`, or use the default if the pack isn't long enough.

Comment: C++17 will buy you heterogeneous variadic non-type parameters, but still no mix.